# How to send another request and get result in scrapy parse function?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm analyzing an HTML page which has a two level menu.
When the top-level menu changed, there's an AJAX request sent to get second-level menu item. When the top and second menu are both selected, then refresh the content.

What I need is **sending another request and get the submenu response** in the scrapy's `parse` function. So I can iterate the submenu, build `scrapy.Request` per submenu item.

The pseudo code like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    top_level_menu = response.xpath('//TOP_LEVEL_MENU_XPATH')
    second_level_menu_items = ## HERE I NEED TO SEND A REQUEST AND GET RESULT, PARSED TO ITME VALUE LIST

    for second_menu_item in second_level_menu_items:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(content_request_url + '？top_level=' + top_level_menu + '&second_level_menu=' + second_menu_item), callback=self.parse_content)
```

How can I do this?

Using `requests` lib directly? Or some other feature provided by scrapy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended approach here is to create another callback (`parse_second_level_menus`?) to handle the response for the second level menu items and in there, create the requests to the content pages.

Also, you can use the `request.meta` attribute to pass data between callback methods ([more info here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments)).

It could be something along these lines:

```
def parse(self, response):
    top_level_menu = response.xpath('//TOP_LEVEL_MENU_XPATH').get()
    yield scrapy.Request(
        some_url,
        callback=self.parse_second_level_menus,
        # pass the top_level_menu value to the other callback
        meta={'top_menu': top_level_menu},
    )

def parse_second_level_menus(self, response):
    # read the data passed in the meta by the first callback
    top_level_menu = response.meta.get('top_menu')
    second_level_menu_items = response.xpath('...').getall()

    for second_menu_item in second_level_menu_items:
        url = response.urljoin(content_request_url + '？top_level=' + top_level_menu + '&second_level_menu=' + second_menu_item)
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url,
            callback=self.parse_content
    )

def parse_content(self, response):
    ...
```

Yet another approach (less recommended in this case) would be using this library: https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests

Comment: How can I get the result of ‘parse_second_level_menus’ in parse function?

Comment: Do you mean I should start the crawler from `parse` function, then start `parse_second_level_menus` to get second level menu, then start `parse_content` to get final content? Is there some approach makes me get second level menu in the function `parse`, just like a sync method call?

Comment: in that case you'd need the package I mentioned by the end of the answer: https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests

Answer (score 0):

Simply use dont_filter=True for your Request
example:

```
def start_requests(self):
    return [Request(url=self.base_url, callback=self.parse_city)]

def parse_city(self, response):
    for next_page in response.css('a.category'):
        url = self.base_url + next_page.attrib['href']
        self.log(url)
        yield Request(url=url,  callback=self.parse_something_else, dont_filter=True)

def parse_something_else(self, response):
    for next_page in response.css('#contentwrapper > div > div > div.component > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr'):
        url = self.base_url + next_page.attrib['href']
        self.log(url)
        yield Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

def parse(self, response):
    pass
```