# Scrape displayed data through onclick using Selenium and Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm doing a script in python using Scrapy in order to scrape data from a website using an authentication.
The page I'm scraping is really painful because mainly made with javascript and AJAX requests. All the body of the page is put inside a `<form>` that allow to change the page using a `submit` button. URL don't change (and it's a .aspx).

I have successfully made that scrape all the data I need from page one, then changing page clicking on this input button using this code :

```
            yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formname="Form",
            clickdata={"class":"PageNext"},
            callback=self.after_login)
```

The `after_login` method is scraping the data.
However I need data that appear in another div after clicking on a container with `onclick` attribute. I need to do a loop in order to click on each container, displaying the data, scraping them and just after that I'm going to the next page and do the same process.

The thing is I can't find how to make the process where "the script" just click on the container using Selenium (while being logged in, if not I cannot go to this page) and then Scrapy is scraping the data that after the XHR request has been made.

I did a lot of research on the internet but could not try any solution.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you have Selenium integrated into your project yet (even if only partially)? Another way to handle Javascript is with [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash).

Comment: Alternatively, did you investigate whether each of those containers do a web request? Like a proper API call or even just returning an HTML snippet? Or do they just switch content that is already loaded?

Comment: There is indeed a form sending data in order to do the AJAX request. I have succeeded in finding form data and an ID value to do a FormRequest but the data is displayed in a popup only appearing using Javascript. Maybe the Form is sending data to be displayed somewhere in, for instance, .json format but I don't really know where to look.

Regarding Splash, do you have a tutorial to use Scrapy Splash request to simulate onclick behavior ? Thanks !

Comment: Can't Scrapy execute javascript function and only update the html body it gets in response ?

Comment: Scrapy only fetches data. If your manually triggered AJAX form submission returns JSON you can parse it, of course. But it won't run any Javascript to update the page. You can inspect the form submission request using your browser's Inspector tool (Firefox/Chrome). [Here is a tutorial](https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash) from the company who built Splash. And [here is a guide](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html) on using the browser's developer tools to inspect the requests.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll check this out. It helps me a lot. After investigated further the request I saw that the response of the request is not .json but HTML. Can Scrapy scrap directly from the response while not being displayed on the HTML page ? Or can't I force the page to display response in HTML ?

Comment: Yes, it can scrape from that response. But you need to do that as a separate Request. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278942/how-to-send-another-request-and-get-result-in-scrapy-parse-function

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding out first if the form I'm sending is giving the right response I want. In fact this "form" is triggered with javascript so there is not real input submit button. Is there a way to get the raw response after sending a form ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check it in the browser? Then you need to use the developer tools to inspect it. Have a look at the link I posted about doing that: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#the-network-tool

Comment: Yes I'm already using the dev tools. What I'm trying to tell is that using dev tools I'm still triggering the sending of the form using ajax (it uses javascript function, that get some data from hidden input values and then, I guess, call the server for the data it sants) but Scrapy is not using ajax but sending the form and I don't know it the process used by Scrapy is giving the same response as when I'm doing it and using JS.

Comment: If the AJAX call is a POST request and you do the same POST request in Scrapy, then you should get the same result. But it is your responsibility to ensure that you send all the correct data in Scrapy. This includes the actual form fields as well as any other required headers. You'll need to work out what is necessary. Can you post the real URL?

Comment: Unfortunately the page need a loggin and you cannot subscribe like that. The Form Data of the ajax request counts around 25 values ! I've taken all the values that change from the html page (from hidden input) but it looks really tricky to do this POST request. Get from scrapy the response from the request would help me doing it (tab "Response" near the "Headers" one in the Network Tools from Chome dev tools)

Comment: The problem to me is that the only AJAX request is not updating the HTML page by itself, seems to require JS to display the AJAX request response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've almost got what I want, following @malberts advices.
I've used this kind of code in order to get the Ajax response request :

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response=response,
            formdata={
                    'param1':param1value,
                    'param2':param2value,
                    '__VIEWSTATE':__VIEWSTATE,
                    '__ASYNCPOST':'true',
                   'DetailsId':'123'},
            callback=self.parse_item)

def parse_item(self, response):
    ajax_response = response.body
    yield{'Response':ajax_response}
```

The response is suppose to be in HTML. Thing is the response is not totally the same as the one when I lookup to the Response request through Chrome Dev Tools. I've not taken all the form data into account yet (~10 / 25), could it be it needs all the form data even if they don't change depending the id ?

Thanks !